# Как отцентровать такие элементы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

вот пример с [Codepen](https://codepen.io/denibudeyko/pen/OJLGyOM)

Как сделать что бы расстояния от левого элемента к зеленому краю было одинакого от правого элемента к правому краю.
Проблема в том что им надо задать 33.333% ( по 3 в ряд) но сами элементы не занимают столько места. И за чего очень дикий разброс. Хотел центрировать центральный элемент по центру, а правый по правому краю, но не получается. Кто бы мог подсказать, спасибо

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.item {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: получиться должно так или как-то иначе?
http://joxi.ru/nAyxYNMSgWo1o2

Answer (score 1):

Просто отцентруйте точки и всё:

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.item {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

так?

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0
}

.item {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.item:nth-child(3n + 2) {
    text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-child(3n + 3) {
    text-align: right;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
  <div class="item"><span></span></div>
</div>
```